# How to set or change cookie value in Chromium?

Tags: delphi, cookies, components, chromium

How to set or change cookie value in Chromium?

This not work:

```
CookieManager := TCefCookieManagerRef.Global;
  CookieManager.VisitAllCookiesProc(
    function(const name, Value, domain, path: ustring;
      secure, httponly, hasExpires: Boolean; const creation, lastAccess,
      expires: TDateTime; Count, total: Integer;
      out deleteCookie: Boolean): Boolean
    begin
      deleteCookie := False;
      ShowMessage(name + ': ' + Value);
      CookieManager.SetCookie('', name, Value + 'aaaa', domain, path, secure,
        httponly, hasExpires, creation, lastAccess, expires);
      Result := True;
    end);
```

Comment: How doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: When I run it again, value has not changed. Should be added 'aaa' to value. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use empty url in SetCookie function, just add url according to domain.

```
SetCookie('http://=your site=/' ...
```

That works correctly.

Also, there is another solution which you don't have to use inside VisitAllCookiesProc

```
  TCefFastTask.New(TID_IO, procedure
    begin
      CookieManager.SetCookie('http://=your site=/'...
    end
  );
```